# What is the name of the function which results from sampling a sigmoid?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, descriptive-statistics

It is not just two Gaussian distributions. I would hope that it is defined and has a name, but I can't find it. I would love to know more about it (parametric formula, how to extract the parameters given a sample...).

[Example Shape resulting of uniform sampling a sigmoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiJMZ.png)

PS: Not particularly of interest, I think, but the above was obtained using this formula:

`sample_normal + 2 / (1 + exp(-0.5*(sample_uniform*20 - 10)))`

... where 'sample_normal' is a sample from a normal distribution(mu=1, sd=0.1, N=500), and 'sample_uniform' is just 500 random numbers from 0 to 1.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: It is not a sigmoid distribution (which has an $\int$ shaped cdf while yours has that shape for its quantile function - the inverse of its cdf).

Comment: It will not have a name: assuming independence, it is the sum of a bimodal random variable with density $\frac{1}{5 x(2-x)}$ between $\frac{2}{e^5+1}\approx 0.0134$ and  $\frac{2}{e^{-5}+1}\approx 1.9866$ plus a narrowly distributed Gaussian random variable.

Comment: I was thinking that it might be related to the inverse of the normal distribution, since the normal is the derivative of the sigmoid. And it makes sense that the lower the gradient (in the sigmoid, where we sample), the more dense the sample points. Your comment shows the inverse of a 2nd degree polynomial, which might adapt to the shape if it is between the roots, excluding them. Then it messes up.